# Aggregate for multiple instances with a ManyToOne relation

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django and I want to build a Website to track boardgames.

What I want: For each round played a Player will get points and I want to create a table which shows the sum of all Scores for each Player.

My model is as follows:

```
class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)

class Score(models.Model):
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player, blank=False, null=False, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    scorevalue = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
```

I would like to get a queryset with all players where an additional field with the sum of his scores is added. In SQL something like

```
Select distinct playername, sum(scorevalue) over (partition by playername) 
from Players 
Join Scores
```

My main problem is to understand the connection between "aggregate" and "annotate" functions in combination with instances and querysets.

With an instance I can get

`Player.objects.get(pk=1).score_set.aggregate(score_sum=Sum('scorevalue'))`

but is it possible to do  this for every instance in a queryset?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in that case you *annotate* the objects, so with:

```
from django.db.models import Sum

Player.objects.annotate(
    score_sum=Sum('score__scorevalue')
)
```

The `Player` objects that arise from this queryset will have an extra attribute `.score_sum` which is the sum of the related `Score` records.

One can make use of two consecutive underscores (`__`) to look "through" relations, and thus access data of related model records.

Comment: Thank you, that works well. So the join is stated inside of the Sum, I always tried to do it first and then annotate on the queryset. Is it possible to do further filtering based on other foreign keys that Score has, like if Round would be a seperate Entity with a connection to Score?

Comment: @thream: you can likely do that with a [`Prefetch` object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-objects), but I would advise to ask a new question, and share the relevant models.

Comment: The filter inside of the sum does the job: Player.objects.annotate(sum_scorevalue=Coalesce(Sum('score__scorevalue', filter=Q(score__round__somebooleanfield=True)), 0))

Comment: @thream: the only problem that might occur with this is that if a `Score` can have *multiple* `round`s, then it will count that score as many times as there are `round`s with `somebooleanfield=True`.